# li items inside table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to place the output of below code in table? The reason is that I want to put headings and nice alignment between firstname and lastname.

Javascript

```
var nameList = document.getElementById('names');

    namearray.push([firstname, lastname]);
    namearray.sort();   

    for(var i = 0; i < namearray.length; i++){

    letters += '<li>' + firstname[i] + " " + lastname[i]+ '</li>';
    nameList.innerHTML = letters;

     }
```

HTML

```
<ul id="names">
```

Comment: Do provide a complete example..

Comment: I updated the code.

Comment: re-update the code and show more code.

Comment: provide a jsfiddle please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var nameList = document.getElementById('names');

namearray.push([firstname, lastname]);
namearray.sort();   


    for(var i = 0; i < namearray.length; i++){

        var row = nameList.insertRow(i);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell1.innerHTML = firstname[i];
        cell2.innerHTML = lastname[i];

     }
```

HTML:

```
<table id="names"></table>
```